# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK with Firebase

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android

Anyone of you have experience implementing Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK with Firebase?

We are using FCM and have tested Marketing Cloud Push SDK version 5.5.0 with Google Play Service SDK version 11.8.0

The developer has followed the implementation guideline on how to handle multiple-push-sdks solution: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

However, there is still duplicate notification shown while we sent the push from firebase console even we’ve the implementation according to the guideline.

As Salesforce is not supporting Firebase, not sure if you know provide any solution/workaround for that.

Comment: Had the same issues unfortunately, found no easy or reliable workaround. Also requested from Salesforce info about firebase since GCM is being sunset from april next year but so far no response.

Comment: The SDK will _not_ show a message that does not contain the Message ID field in the payload: `_m` for reference.  Please omit this field when sending from Firebase.  The only other way for a duplicate notification to be shown is if you are handling notification processing yourself and still return a valid `Notification.Builder`.  We are aware of the transition to FCM and will be notifying customers in the near future.